# Does a salt and pepper password count as 96-bit encryption?

Tags: php, security, encryption, passwords, md5

I have created this code for a salt and pepper password encryption. I assume this is a good way to encrypt passwords, but what level of encryption is this?

I first thought the 'bit' part was the length of characters used but I know that is incorrect.  How many bits of encryption would this be?

**PHP**

```
function _h() {
  $result = "";
  $charPool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  for($p = 0; $p<32; $p++)
    $result .= $charPool[mt_rand(0,strlen($charPool)-1)];
  return md5(sha1(md5(sha1($result))));
}

$salt = _h();
$pepper = _h();
$pass = $salt.md5($salt.md5($_POST['password']).$pepper).$pepper;
```

**UPDATE**

I understand this is not encryption, so I would not be able to say this is encrypted, but instead hashed.  Is a hashed password with a salt and pepper secure enough to save a password?

Comment: It is known (just search SE for it), so trivially broken.

Comment: Never leave security to someone who's not an expert. If you're not an expert yourself, use an expert's work–for instance, [blowfish](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) (`crypt` with `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`).

Comment: That's not encryption, that's hashing.  This also reeks of cargo-cult cryptography. "sha is weak, and md5 is weak, but salts are good, so if I use lots of all of those, and mix them up, the result must be good!"

Comment: [Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) is not [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption)!

Comment: Is this not a good way to encrypt password then?  Are there any code examples of `crypt` that I can use?

Comment: If in Unix, use `crypt(3)`. If you want to create passwords, there are lots of password generators around, or this [advise](http://www.xkcd.org/936).

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanations! I will use a premade password generator from now one, as @zneak said, leave the security to an expert.  I'm a developer, not a security expert.

Comment: [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) makes it easier to do it right. `HashPassword` (as shown in the `test.php` file in the first few couple of lines) will use Blowfish if it's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a lot of problems with your scheme to hash a password.

PHP 5.5 will have it's own functions password_hash() and password_verify() ready, to simplify generating BCrypt password hashes. I strongly recommend to use this excellent api, or it's [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) for earlier PHP versions. The usage is very straightforward:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

These functions will solve following problems:

1. They use a slow adaptable hash function (BCrypt), MD5 is ways too fast for hashing passwords.
2. They generate a safe salt from the random source of the operating system.

A pepper is not just a second salt, in contrast to a salt, the pepper is secret and will not be stored together with the hash. The same pepper will normally be used for all passwords.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is not immediately obvious to web developers, and I'm sure a majority of them still use `MD5` within their projects. Thanks for also clearing up my usage of a 'pepper'.

Comment: @Titanium - You are right, that despite frequent headlines about stolen password databases, MD5 is still recommended again and again. Maybe you could be interested reading my [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php) about secure password hashing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no use in complicating the computation of `salt` and `$peppr` too much. After all the task is not the retrieval of what was originally used to produce these spices but  trather the value of `$_POST('a']` and you *give away* the `$salt`and `$pepper` as prefix/suffix (otherwise you couldn't use the stored valuelater to *verify* an input password with this hash). That being said, do as @zneak commented and use an expert library function.